# AngularJS - $resource different URL for Get and Post

Tags: angularjs

$resource is awesome providing very convenient way to handle web services.
What if GET and POST have to be performed on different URLs?

For example, GET URL is `http://localhost/pleaseGethere/:id`
and POST URL is `http://localhost/pleasePosthere` without any parameter

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should be able to expose the URL as a parameter. I was able to do this:

```
$provide.factory('twitterResource', [
    '$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource(
            'https://:url/:action',
            {
                url: 'search.twitter.com',
                action: 'search.json',
                q: '#ThingsYouSayToYourBestFriend',
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            },
            {
                get: {
                    method: 'JSONP'
                }
            }
        );
    }
]);
```

Then you can overwrite the URL on your `GET` call.

The one caveat I found during my REALLY brief testing was that if I included `http://` in the URL string, it didn't work. I didn't get an error message. It just did nothing.

Comment: The problem is that the url paramenter gets encoded, that's why 'http://' or anything with a '/' will fail. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zymotik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944932/angularjs-resource-how-to-disable-url-entity-encoding

Comment: This answer is a bit too convoluted for what the asker was looking for - Iris's answer is on point.

Answer (score 55):

Use 'url' property of [actions] to override the default url.

```
$resource(url, [paramDefaults], [actions], options);
```

for example:

```
$resource('http://localhost/pleaseGethere/:id',{},{
    getMethod:{
        method:'GET',
        isArray:true
    }
    postMethod:{
        url:'http://localhost/pleasePosthere',
        method:'POST',
        isArray:false
    }
}
```

Usage of Angular $resource: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: That `:id` used in the "base" url is also available in the postMethod url. +1!

Answer (score 9):

If you add the hash with param names into the $resource call:

```
$resource('localhost/pleaseGethere/:id', {id: '@id'});
```

Then the :id will be mapped to *id* param when invoking the function (this will call *GET localhost/pleaseGethere/123*):

```
Resource.get({id: 123});
```

For POST, you simply don't assign the *id* param:

```
Resource.post({}, {name: "Joe"});
```

The proper URL will be called, which is in this case *POST localhost/pleaseGethere* (the trailing slash is stripped by ngResource).

See [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) -> Examples -> Credit card resource for more details.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Iris Wong's answer, I wanted to give an example of having multiple params with multiple methods and actions:

```
angular
  .module('thingApp')
  .factory('ThingResource', ['$resource', '$state',  returnThing]);
```

And the resource:

```
function returnThing($resource, $state) {
  var mainUrl = '/api/stuffs/:stuffId/thing'
  var params = {stuffId: '@_id', thingMongoId: '@_id', thingNumber: '@_id'}
  return $resource(mainUrl, params, {
    'save': {
      url: '/api/stuffs/:stuffId/thing/:thingMongoId',
      method: 'POST',
      interceptor: {
        responseError: function(e) {
          console.warn('Problem making request to backend: ', e)
          $state.go('oops')
        }
      }
    },
    'get': {
      url: '/api/stuffs/:stuffId/thing/:thingMongoId',
      method: 'GET',
      interceptor: {
        responseError: function(e) {
          console.warn('Problem making request to backend: ', e)
          $state.go('oops')
        }
      }
    },
    'assignThing':{
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/stuffs/:stuffId/thing/assign/:thingNumber'
    }
  });
}
```

Which gives 3 separate methods:

```
// POST to http://currnt_base_url/api/stuffs/:stuffId/thing/:thingMongoId
ThingResource.save({
    stuffId:'56c3d1c47fe68be29e0f7652', 
    thingMongoId: '56c3d1c47fe6agwbe29e0f11111'})

// GET to current http://currnt_base_url/api/stuffs/:stuffId/thing/:thingMongoId
ThingResource.get({
    stuffId:'56c3d1c47fe68be29e0f7652', 
    thingMongoId: '56c3d1c47fe6agwbe29e0f11111'})

// POST to http://currnt_base_url/api/stuffs/:stuffId/thing/assign/:thingNumber
ThingResource.assignThing({
    stuffId:'56c3d1c47fe68be29e0f7652', 
    thingNumber: '999998'})
```

Comment: comprehensive and valuable. +1

Answer (score 1):

Follow this way:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module("app")
        .factory("SomeFactory", SomeFactory);

    function SomeFactory($resource) {
        var provider = "http://stackoverflow.com/:action/:id";
        var params = {"id":"@id"};
        var actions = {
            "create":   {"method": "POST",  "params": {"action": "CreateAwesomePost"}},
            "read":     {"method": "POST",  "params": {"action": "ReadSomethingInteresting"}},
            "update":   {"method": "POST",  "params": {"action": "UpdateSomePost"}},
            "delete":   {"method": "GET",   "params": {"action": "DeleteJustForFun"}}
        };

        return $resource(provider, params, actions);
    }
})();
```

I hope it help! Enjoy!