# angularjs $location encodes url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, encodeuricomponent

I am using $location service to set query string in the url like this one :

```
$location.search('prefix','s/5469b2f5b4292d22522e84e0/ms.files/images/');
```

But it is showing url like this :

```
?prefix=s%2F5469b2f5b4292d22522e84e0%2Fms.files%2Fimages%2F
```

I don't want to encode it and need like this one

```
?prefix=s/5469b2f5b4292d22522e84e0/ms.files/images/
```

Comment: It's what it's supposed to do and what HTTP specifications tell you to do. GET parameters have to be URL encoded.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve it ?

Comment: No, you'll have to "URL-decode" the value server-side.

Comment: but aws is doing this thing : https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=myregion1#&bucket=mybucket&prefix=s/5469b2f5b4292d22522e84e0/ms.files/           i was working in aws admin panel and from there i got this url

Comment: It really depends on the server they are using. The standard says `/` should be encoded to `%2F`. Whatever AWS is using does not enforce this rule. Regarding what you could to to make this work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944932/angularjs-resource-how-to-disable-url-entity-encoding