# ng-Table sorting and searching not working when use $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource, ngtable

i started with an existing example of ngTable an modified it a bit to use ngResource. using resource factory it populates the data but searching and sorting doesn't works.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVGKMZ

Created a pen above.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable", "ngResource", "ngTableDemoFakeBackend"]);

app.factory('orderResource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
});

(function () {

    app.controller("demoController", demoController);
    demoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "$resource", "orderResource"];
    function demoController(NgTableParams, $resource, orderResource) {
        //debugger;
        var ordersGet = orderResource.query({ });


        var Api = $resource("/data");
        this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
            getData: function (params) {

                // **** Section 1 ***  sorting and filter does not work
                    return ordersGet.$promise.then(function (response) {
                    params.total(100);
                    return response;
              // **** Section 1 *** 
              
              
                //****Section 2 *** this works fine
                    // return Api.get(params.url()).$promise.then(function(data) {
                    //           params.total(data.inlineCount);  
                    //           return data.results;
              //****Section 2 ***
              
              
                });
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="demoController as demo">



        <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
            <tr ng-repeat="row in $data track by row.id">
                <td data-title="'iss'" filter="{id: 'number'}" sortable="'id'">{{row.id}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the code if you comment section 1 and un comment section 2 you can observe it working. 
i also tried simple $http it didn't worked as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular Table sorting does not work if i use a different api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230583/angular-table-sorting-does-not-work-if-i-use-a-different-api)

I asked the same question else where and got a better answer.

First thing was, we were missing filtering.

```
return $filter('filter')($filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()),params.filter());
```

and to make sorting work we had to add some logic to remove properties with null filter values.

working code pen is here

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWRNjQ

Answer (score 4):

Well I think I've solved it - probably not the cleanest one but still...

```
  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable", "ngResource", "ngTableDemoFakeBackend"]);

app.factory('orderResource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
});

(function () {

app.controller("demoController", demoController);
demoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "$resource", "orderResource", '$filter'];
function demoController(NgTableParams, $resource, orderResource, $filter) {
    //debugger;
    var ordersGet = orderResource;


    var Api = $resource("/data");
    this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
        getData: function (params) {
            // **** Section 1 ***  sorting and filter does not work
                return orderResource.query().$promise.then(function (response) {
                params.total(100);

                return $filter('orderBy')($filter('filter')(response, params.filter()), params.orderBy())
          // **** Section 1 ***    

            //****Section 2 *** this works fine
                // return Api.get(params.url()).$promise.then(function(data) {
                //           params.total(data.inlineCount);  
                //           return data.results;
          //****Section 2 ***


            });
        }
    });
}
})();
```

I've applied $filter service and I'm ordering table results by this filter ( sorting order I already have from component )

Comment: Thanx mate. i got what you meant but with this approach searching still doesn't work.

Comment: Hey I've solved searching - take a look at my update

Comment: yes this is almost the same as answer given below. searching doesn't clears up when filter is cleared because it makes the number filters
 {id: null} 
so there was a code injected to  remove null values. 

not a clean way but kind of works. 

but if you see ng table examples.  they simply work in all cases, without any manual interference.

Comment: Not necessarily, if you take a closer look when data is fetched from backend via getData function then you can clearly see that data is sorted on backend not by component itself. You can see that component do not provide itself sorting for fetched data by ajax because every time you sort then getData is loaded for fetching data. That's why your section 2 example works ( it is sorted on backend and not on frontend ). Even on ngTable site you have example with sorting on backend based on parameters from ngTable.

Answer (score 0):

Your Line

```
 var ordersGet = orderResource.query({ });
```

Is clearing out the `query` command for your `ordersGet` variable. So when you do

return `ordersGet.$promise.then` there isnt really an ajax call taking place. Nothing is really going on. `ngTable` calls your `ordersGet` but since the `query` command is nothing, it does nothing.

in addition, if some how your `ordersGet` was working  you never pass the `params.url()` so the pagination would never work.

In my opinion there are two ways of doing this

1. just use your

> Section 2 solution and be done with it

2. Override the `get` URL on your resource and call it similar to this `ordersGet(params.url()).$promise.then();` Which is much more complicated, but here are a few links to go down that route.

[Great SO question on how to override resource URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633904/angularjs-resource-different-url-for-get-and-post)

Comment: i tried this, didn't worked.
app.factory('orderResource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {}, {
            get:    {method: 'GET'},
            update: {method: 'POST'}
        });
});