# Angular Table sorting does not work if i use a different api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ngtable

i took ngTable example from

http://ng-table.com/#/loading/demo-external-array

opened it in code pen and instead of "/data" i am using an api

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

and added isArray : true

```
  var Api = $resource("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {}, {
    'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: true}
});
```

in html i took out all the columns and kept "id" column for simplicity

it loads id column but searching sorting does not work.

what is it that i am doing wrong ?

changed pen is here

http://codepen.io/raasmasood/pen/zoeMgx

Comment: I believe your filter should be on your <tr> because that is the item being repeated to create your table rows

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: i tired it. it didn't worked. i think there is something with the promise. i dont know exactly what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWRNjQ

you could check this codepen, now it works. ;)

```
getData: function(params) {
    // ajax request to api
    return Api.get(params.url()).$promise.then(function(data) {
     params.total(100); // recal. page nav controls
     return ($filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()));
      //return data;
    });
  }
```

Previously there we missed the filter part.

```
return $filter('filter')($filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()),params.filter());
```

for enabling filter too :)

Comment: its great. sorting works. but filter does not work when we clear it.

Comment: i think its the same problem mentioned in answer above.

Comment: This is a tricky one http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWRNjQ  this will do the work. Have updated the function getData.

Comment: yes i got it working with the same concept of removing a property with a null value but your code is more generic. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up doing the sort/filter/paging manually:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable", "ngResource", "ngTableDemoFakeBackend"]);
(function() {

  app.controller("demoController", demoController);
  demoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "$resource", "$filter"];

  function demoController(NgTableParams, $resource, $filter) {
  //var Api = $resource("/data");
    var Api = $resource("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {}, {
      // Let's make the `query()` method cancellable
      query: {method: 'get', isArray: true, cancellable: true}
    });        

    this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({      
      count: 5
    }, {

      getData: function(params) {
        // ajax request to api
        return Api.query().$promise.then(function(data) {

         params.total(data.length); // recal. page nav controls

          var filteredData = params.filter().id  ?
                      $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
                         data;

          var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
              $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : data;
          var page = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

          return page;
        });
      }
    });

  }
})();
```

The downside with this approach is since you are using filtering, the more columns you add the more checking you need to do because the way it works, when you clear the filter it will not set that object to undefined. It will create an object like this:

```
{ id: null }
```

Which means you cannot use `params.filter()` in this line:

```
var filteredData = params.filter().id  ?
                  $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
                     data;
```

Comment: exactly. i had to include a $watch to make it work. but still looking for the solution without manual stuff